# Start sentence with verb

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase-usage, verbs

Avoid or quit smoking, the chemicals in cigarette smoke harm your respiratory system.
can I use avoid or quit like this.
How can I write this sentence grammatically correct

Comment: **Quit** applies to smokers. **Avoid** to non smokers. Prefer one or the other. Alternatively, **Don't smoke** would apply to both. And use a semi-colon instead of a comma. (Such admonitions work best when they are short and sharp, as in: **Quit smoking: it bungs up your lungs**.)

Answer (score 0):

Imperatives in English usually start the sentence so

> Avoid smoking
> Quit smoking

would both be fine. It is also possible to have two or more linked by a conjunction although your example does not lend itself neatly to that

> Eat, drink and be merry, for tomorrow we die

is an example.

Answer (score -1):

Quit/stop smoking or the chemicals in cigarettes will harm you.

Comment: Best read through your answers before you post them to make sure that you've got your singulars and plurals right.